# the command line displays information from the mysql database incorrectly

Tags: mysql

[image]

When requesting information from the database, it is displayed incorrectly. I ask for help in this matter.

Comment: Use Mysql Query browser. https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/query/

Answer (score 0):

because your console screen is small and

may number of columns in the table is big

you cant export it into a file

like--

```
SELECT * FROM table
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/file.txt'
```

Comment: if you expand the console to full screen, then nothing changes

Comment: first expand your screen then select again.

Comment: I am clearly seeing that your query result is crossing the screen because the result length is larger than your console. I think you can use phpmyadmin if you need it regularly